# Show that 4*AB=CAB is not possible

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

Show that 4*AB=CAB is not possible.Each letter denotes a single digit.It could be noted that since LHS is a multiple of 4,thus RHS would also be a multiple of 4.That's all i conclude yet...

Comment: is $A=B=C=0$ excluded?

Comment: $A=0, B=0, C=0$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: what digit $d$ has the property that $4 \times d$ ends in $d$?

Answer (score 2):

Well, a start could be to treat AB as a variable, $AB = \alpha$ and solve

$4*\alpha = C*100 + \alpha$

If this equation has no solutions where $\alpha$ is a whole number with two digits, then the original statement is not possible since $\alpha$ is AB, which is a whole number with two digits.

Oh, and C has to be between 0 and 9 too right?

Comment: +1 Nice method, other than the standard solution. You could manipulate the equation to get $\alpha=\frac{100}{3}C$. Now will it have any solution for C in 0 to 9?

Comment: ...For values of $C=0, 3, 6, 9$, the RHS will be an integer, and hence are the solutions. But for $C\geq 3$, $\alpha >100$, whihc is not allowed. Hence the only solution, $A=0, B=0, C=0$.